# Slow tomcat response and how to solve it

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, servlets, tomcat8

Client sends the request to our system and it shows slow response. The client sees for example 9sec for one request. We have nginx -- tomcat8 -- our servlet.
Nginx shows the same slow response from tomcat. But I created the Filter around servlet and added logging in filter and servlet. And java logging shows that response is 0.6 sec. The response is very simple just 200 code with couple headers and that's all. I checked GC logs and there's nothing special at this time.

So now I don't understand what can take remaining 8 sec. It seems something inside tomcat but how to understand and monitor it?

Env: JDK 8, Tomcat 8, Linux Debian Jessie.

Java Run Params:

```
    echo 'JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xmx10500m -Xms10500m"' >> $TOMCAT_CONFIG
    echo 'JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -Xloggc:/var/log/tomcat8/garbagecollector.log"' >> $TOMCAT_CONFIG
    echo 'JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+PrintPromotionFailure"' >> $TOMCAT_CONFIG

    echo 'JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"' >> $TOMCAT_CONFIG
    echo 'JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8999"' >> $TOMCAT_CONFIG
    echo 'JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"' >> $TOMCAT_CONFIG
    echo 'JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"' >> $TOMCAT_CONFIG
    echo 'JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"' >> $TOMCAT_CONFIG
    echo 'JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing"' >> $TOMCAT_CONFIG

    echo 'JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"' >> $TOMCAT_CONFIG
    echo 'JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled"' >> $TOMCAT_CONFIG
    echo 'JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled"' >> $TOMCAT_CONFIG
    echo 'JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark"' >> $TOMCAT_CONFIG
    echo 'JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=50"' >> $TOMCAT_CONFIG
    echo 'JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=80"' >> $TOMCAT_CONFIG
    echo 'JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly"' >> $TOMCAT_CONFIG
    echo 'JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:CMSWaitDuration=30000"' >> $TOMCAT_CONFIG

    echo 'JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:MaxNewSize=2512m -XX:NewSize=2512m -XX:+UseParNewGC"' >> $TOMCAT_CONFIG
    echo 'JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:SurvivorRatio=14"' >> $TOMCAT_CONFIG
    echo 'JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1"' >> $TOMCAT_CONFIG

    echo 'JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow"' >> $TOMCAT_CONFIG

    echo 'JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=60"' >> $TOMCAT_CONFIG
    echo 'JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/log/tomcat8/OOME.hprof"' >> $TOMCAT_CONFIG

    echo 'ulimit -n 65535' >> $TOMCAT_CONFIG
```

Comment: Is nginx and tomcat running on the same machine? I'm just trying to make sure we can eliminate the obvious network lag.

Comment: yes, they are on the same server.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your whole environment? OS, JDK version, and whatnot?

Comment: tomcat: 8.0.32, jdk: 8u131, OS: linux debian 8.6

Comment: Where did you get these run parameters?  Have you tried it with the out of the box parameters (other than, perhaps, memory)?  You're using time logging garbage collection and you're using options that are no longer supported in Java 8.

Comment: @stdunbar it's legacy system and maybe we have some old params but I think they don't do things which I described in my question.

Comment: What's the number of tomcat threads and how much threads are available (i.e. not running)? Filter doesn't include queueing time for a request.

Comment: @bashnesnos here's munin graph: 
https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4258/34725019010_a53cc3061c_z_d.jpg  Max thread: 500 but max busy threads: 13 so the problem isn't in waiting threads.

Comment: If you turn on access logs on nginx including response time, what would you see as a response time?

Comment: @bashnesnos I see something like this: [04/May/2017:18:52:14 +0000] 8.681 10.253.36.4 "GET /ar?_ar_reason_desc=internal_timeout&_ar_reason_detail=java.net.SocketTimeoutException%3A+Read+timed+out&_ar_reason_id=1030 HTTP/1.1" 200 0 143 - "8.681"  where first 8.681 is time from nginx to external service. and second "8.681" is time from tomcat to nginx. So the problem is not network but somewhere in tomcat.